# Minecraft forge cannot resolve symbol 'net'

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I've just tried to write a Minecraft mod. IntelliJ IDEA highlighted this line of code: `import net.minecraftforge.registries.DefferdRegister;` with the following error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'net'
```

How can this be solved? Forge build: 1.16.4-35.1.36

Comment: You don't have all of the dependencies/libraries added to your build file/path.

Comment: Just ran build.grandle after replacing 'examplemod' with my mod name...

Answer (score 0):

Some libraries are missing, run the command `gradlew eclipse` to add those libraries.
Make sure that you run this command in the project folder. It will take some time, but it will solve your issue.